# NoMethodError in Story#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It says `undefined method`stories_path'`.

Hi, I have been trying to figure out the solution to the above error for a while, to no avail. I also am receiving an error in my terminal as well:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `stories_path' for #<#<Class:0x005557c1a40560>:0x005557c1885cc0>
Did you mean?  story_path):
    1: <%= form_for @story do |f| %>
    2:   <%= render 'shared/errors', object: @story %>
    3: 
    4:   <div class="form-group">
```

I have a feeling it might be to do with my routes but I am unsure of how to change the configuration.

My controller:

```
class StoryController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_story, only: [:destroy, :show, :edit, :update]


def index
    @stories = Story.order('created_at DESC')
end

def new
    @story = Story.new
end

def create
    @story = Story.new(story_params)
    if @story.save
        flash[:success] = "Your beautiful story has been added!"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
end

def update
    if @story.update.attributes(story_params)
        flash[:success] = "More knowledge, more wisdom"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    if @story.destroy
        flash[:success] = "I think you should have more confidence in your storytelling"
    else
        flash[:error] = "Can't delete this story, sorry"
    end
end

def show
    @stories = Story.all
end

private

def story_params
    params.require(:story).permit(:title, :body)
end

def find_story
    @story = Story.find(params[:id])
end


end
```

new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @story do |f| %>

 <%= render 'shared/errors', object: @story %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: 'form-control', required: true, cols: 3 %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit 'Post', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

My routes.rb file:

Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
devise_for :users
resources :story
root to: 'story#index'
end
```

and finally, /shared/_errors.html.erb

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div class="panel panel-danger">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">The following errors were found while submitting the form:</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul>
        <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Added information: `rake routes | grep stories` does not work. However, `rake routes | grep story` display these results:

```
  story_index GET    /story(.:format)               story#index
                         POST   /story(.:format)               story#create
               new_story GET    /story/new(.:format)           story#new
              edit_story GET    /story/:id/edit(.:format)      story#edit
                   story GET    /story/:id(.:format)           story#show
                         PATCH  /story/:id(.:format)           story#update
                         PUT    /story/:id(.:format)           story#update
                         DELETE /story/:id(.:format)           story#destroy
                    root GET    /                              story#index
```

Comment: can you also post the output of `rake routes | grep stories`

Comment: One more tip - your controller name should be `StoriesController`

Comment: Oh really? I have added more information above. I think this is uncovering the unfortunate reality here! What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can confirm: use plural form for resourceful routes: `/stories`.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest is to follow "convention over configuration" and use the defaults that Rails expects.

So in your routes.rb

```
resources :stories
root to: 'stories#index'
```

rename `app/controllers/story_controller.rb` to `app/controllers/stories_controller.rb` and change the class definition to

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
```

The rest should all work.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I appreciate the rapid responses. I find it hard to understand when I am meant to pluralise!

Comment: Models are singular, e.g. `class Story < ApplicationRecord` but controllers and view folders are plural.  For instance variables, use whatever is appropriate to the context, so `index` (a list of objects) would be `@stories` and `edit` or `show` (a slingle object) would be `@story`

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is you are using singular name for controller and routes

You need to change following

**routes.rb**

```
resources :stories
```

**stories_controller.rb**

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
end
```

which will give you the following routes

```
stories    GET    /stories(.:format)          stories#index
           POST   /stories(.:format)          stories#create
new_story  GET    /stories/new(.:format)      stories#new
edit_story GET    /stories/:id/edit(.:format) stories#edit
story      GET    /stories/:id(.:format)      stories#show
           PATCH  /stories/:id(.:format)      stories#update
           PUT    /stories/:id(.:format)      stories#update
           DELETE /stories/:id(.:format)      stories#destroy
```

And then the form will get `stories_path` properly while creating new story